# Connected to APNS but Message is not Delivered

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement APNS in my app for a week already. I managed to get through the connection timeout problem by contacting my remote server's support to open the ports 2195/6.

And now my next problem is that, when I execute my PHP script, it successfully connect to the APNS server but doesn't deliver the message to the iOS device. Here's my PHP script:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '---------devicetokenwithnospace-----';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'mypassword';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = "New dispatched load!"; 


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PushCertificateAndKey.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
  'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
  $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
  exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
  'alert' => $message,
  'sound' => 'default',
  'category' => "NEWS_CATEGORY",
  );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = '{"aps" : { "alert" : { "title" : "My Title", "body" : "My Message" }, "badge" : 2, "sound" : "default" }}';

echo $payload;

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
echo $result;
if (!$result)
  echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
  echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

The result would be: `Connected to APNS {"aps" : { "alert" : { "title" : "My Title", "body" : "My Message" }, "badge" : 2, "sound" : "default" }}142Message successfully delivered`

As you can see, the `$result` variable returns 142, and I don't know what does it mean.

I tested if the deviceToken I am using is correct by using APN Tester (and it is working, I am able to receive a notification:
[image]

I don't know how to solve this now.

Comment: Why does the certificate you are using in APN tester and the one in the php script have a different name?  And why do the comments say you're encoding as json but then not, and ignoring the body. Try this $payload = json_encode($body);

Comment: The one in the APN tester is the aps_development.cer. But the one in my server is the combination of push certificate and my key. Is that wrong? regarding the $payload, if I change it to `json_encode($body)`, the $result now gives me `122`

Comment: Combining the certificate and key into the pem and using that is no problem.

Comment: So that will not be an issue here.

Comment: If you still can't get things to work after changing the payload, you could try re-creating the .pem just in case you made  a mistake previously. Mistyped the password, included the wrong certificate or key etc.